# Why is history.getState().data empty?

Tags: javascript, history.js, html5-history

I'm using historyjs to manage access to the HTML5 API, and I'm running into a problem where my popped state data is blank:

```
    // Bind to State Change
    history.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function ()
    { 
        if (!self.navigateEnabled)
            return;

        //get the state
        var state = history.getState();

        //use state data here, but it's empty....
    });
```

This is on an AJAX page, and when the user chooses from a `select` element, I push state that is definitely a valid object with various properties:

```
history.pushState(this.data, "", url);
```

What could be causing this?